Mapping in component with Redux and getting error noticesType.map is not a function
I have all the needed working pieces of the React Redux-toolkit working but I can't seem to get my data to display in the component. I'm getting the error:

TypeError: noticesType.map is not a function
 31 |             {noticesType.map((post, index) => { 
    |                          ^
 32 |               <li key={index}>


When I see is that I'm most likely passing an object when it's looking for an array. I am pretty sure I have it set up correctly. I have The Redux-DevTools open, and it shows me the correct data coming back from the API call. After 3 days of searching the web, this is where I'm at. If there is more code or anything I've missed please let me know.
page.tsx
export default function page() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { Notices, loading, error } = useAppSelector(
    state => state.noticesReducer
  )
  console.log('Values: ')
  console.log(Notices)
  
  useEffect(() => { 
    dispatch(fetchNotices())
  }, [dispatch])
  
  return (
    <>
      <div> 
        <h1>Notices</h1>
        <ul>  
          <>    
            {Notices.map((post, index) => { 
              <li key={index}>
                {post.Title}
              </li>
            })}                
          
          </>                
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

noticesTypes.ts Updated with JSON to TypeScript tool.
export interface Root {
   Notices: Notice[]
   CreatedDateTime: string
   Version: number
   Title: string
}
  
export interface Notice {
 id: string
 Title: string
 Description: string
 ChangeRecordNumber: any
 StartDateTime: string
 EndDateTime: string
 Planned: boolean
 ImpactType: string    
}

notice.ts / noticeSlice
type NoticeState = Root & {
  loading: boolean,
  error: boolean,
}

const initialState: NoticeState = {
  Notices: [],
  loading: false,
  error: false
}

export const fetchNotices = createAsyncThunk(
  'fetchNotices',
  async (thunkApi, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://API_CALL/notice")
      return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue("Something isn't working");
    }
  }
);

export const noticeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'notices',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setNotice: (state, action) => { 
      state.Notices = action.payload
    }, 
    getNotice: (state, action) => { 
      return action.payload.notices
    },         
  }, 
  extraReducers: (builder) => { 
    builder
      .addCase(fetchNotices.pending, (state, action) => {            
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(fetchNotices.fulfilled, (state, action) => {             
        state.loading = false, 
        state.Notices = action.payload
      })
      .addCase(fetchNotices.rejected, (state, { payload }) => { 
        state.loading = true                       
      })
  }
})

export const { 
  getNotice,
  setNotice,     
} = noticeSlice.actions

export default noticeSlice.reducer

index.ts / store
export const store = configureStore({ 
  reducer: { 
    noticesReducer, 
  }, 
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({ serializableCheck: false })
})

console.log(store.getState()); 

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch

JSON coming back from API call.
{
  "Notices": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "Title": "test title 1",
      "Description": "Fake Notice: this is fake",            
      "StartDateTime": "2024-09-18",
      "EndDateTime": "2024-09-26",
      "Planned": true,            
      "ImpactedApps": [
        {
          "Id": "1",
          "Name": "Api 1"
        }
      ],       
      "IsActive": true
    }, 
    {
      "id": "2",
      "Title": "test title 2",
      "Description": "Fake Notice: this is fake",            
      "StartDateTime": "2024-09-18",
      "EndDateTime": "2024-09-26",
      "Planned": true,            
      "ImpactedApps": [
        {
          "Id": "2",
          "Name": "Api 2"
        }
      ],       
      "IsActive": true
    }
  ],
  "CreatedDateTime": "2024-09-18",
  "Version": 1,
  "Title": "Notification Feed"
}

Here is an image of what's in the console when I console.log() it out.

Here is the Notices expanded


If noticesType.map is not a function then noticesType is not an array.  When you debug, what value does noticesType have when the error occurs?  How does that value differ from what you expect?  What value did you expect it to have and, based on the code shown, why specifically do you expect that?

noticeType is of type noticesType: NoticeType[] when I hover over it in VS code. when I console it out it says {Notices: Array(3), CreatedDateTime: '2024-09-18T14:50:00.4517665-05:00', Version: 1, Title: 'Notification Feed' So this is what I was expecting.

If that's what you were expecting then the code should produce that error.  What's logged to the console there is an object, not an array.  Is your intent to call .map() on that Notices property on the object instead?

FWIW Typescript is a compile-time "check", once the app is built it's all basically Javascript at run-time and you can do all Javascript things, including breaking your state type invariant. Check all your actions that change the noticesType and verify they are the values with shape/types you are expecting.

Also from your comment that log output doesn't appear to match any of the types you shared in your post.

If you could paste an image of the console, it would be better.

@vsnikhilvs I added and image of the console. @David I was hoping to get all the data if needed but the most of the the data I need is in the Notices property.

@whisk: And indeed you have all of the data.  All of that data is in the form of an object.  You can't call .map() on an object.  Do you want to call .map() on noticesType.Notices?  Have you tried doing that?  Overall it just seems that you're somewhat confused by the data model(s) you're using.  You need to know the structure of the data in order to use it.

@David Ya I've tried to access noticesType.Notices and it says Property 'Notices' does not exist on type 'NoticeType[]' So I guess I'm a little lost on setting the data models up correctly.

@whisk: TypeScript is only helpful if you know the structures of your types.  In this case it sounds like you don't, so your options are either (1) use plain JavaScript instead or (2) update your type definitions to match the data structures being used.  Using terms like "NoticeType" and "NoticesType" also confuse plurality, so you're kind of just continuing to confuse yourself.  Now would be a good time for you to remove your type definitions and re-create them as needed, examining the data structure(s) you're using as you create them.

The data you are logging has a Notices array, but no noticesType array that your state type has. I think this is the discrepancy. Either edit/update your type declarations to match the data you are fetching (and by extension what the UI is rendering), or process the response value into the data shape your Redux store/state slice is saying it manages.

I also totally agree with @David here in that your type names are also causing further confusion. I'd like to add that appending Type to the already obvious interface/type declaration doesn't provide any additional useful information. Something like type Notice = { ... } and type Notices = Notice[] are more informative.

@David @Drew Reese Updated the Data Models with JSON to TypeScript tool based on the object returned from the api, hope that makes things a little more clear. I'm also wondering if its not even looking at the the data model and just sending back the values from the Thunk call? I'm fairly new to all this React JS/TS/JSX.

@whisk: And did this correct the issue?  Is your object now of type Root, and has a property called Notices containing an array on which you can call .map()?  You've made changes, now is a good time to test the code and update anything else that needs to be updated.  When doing so, what problem do you encounter and what question do you have?

@David so after spending a good part of the day testing and trying new things it looks to me that I'm trying to map thru an object and you can only do that with arrays. So I've been trying to convert the object into an array and iterate thru that but no luck yet. Also added the JSON coming back from the API to see if it helps.

@whisk: What specifically do you mean by "convert the object into an array"?  What resulting array are you attempting to create?  I thought the intended functionality was to call .map() on the Notices property of the object, to iterate over that array.  Are you trying to do something different?  It's not clear what the problem is.

Did you mean to use something like state.Notices= action.payload.Notices so the Notices array of the response object is set to the Notices state?

@David I guess my problem is that I am calling an API thru a Redux Thunk call and when I pass whats returned to the desired component and try to map over it to display, I'm getting the above error. I don't know why I'm getting this error. It looks like I'm passing an object into .map() that only takes arrays. What I'm trying to do is display everything that is in the Notice object and am stuck there.

@whisk: Again, it's critical that you understand the structure of the data you're using.  When you say "display everything that is in the Notice object" what specifically do you mean?  Previously it appeared that you wanted to .map() over the elements in the Notices array on that object.  Is that no longer the case?  Do you now also want data from the rest of the object for some reason, and not just from that one array property?  You seem very confused about what your actual goal even is, and are just trying random things to make the error go away without understanding the goal.

@whisk: To put it another way... If the Notices state value is the root of the object shown, and if that object has a property called Notices which contains an array of objects, and if you want to call .map() on that property, then just call .map() on that property and not on the root object.  But currently you keep indicating that you want to "convert the object to an array" and "display everything in the object".  This makes it unclear what you are trying to do.

@DrewReese your recommendation worked for me.  adding Notices to the end of the action.payload.Notices allowed me to .map() over the desired items. Thank you.

Issue
The issue is that you are not maintaining a valid state invariant. At some point during the execution of your code you modified state.Notices from an array type to something else, likely the entire javascript object that is the response value from the fetchNotices action.
Given the following response value:
{
  "Notices": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "Title": "test title 1",
      "Description": "Fake Notice: this is fake",            
      "StartDateTime": "2024-09-18",
      "EndDateTime": "2024-09-26",
      "Planned": true,            
      "ImpactedApps": [
        {
          "Id": "1",
          "Name": "Api 1"
        }
      ],       
      "IsActive": true
    }, 
    {
      "id": "2",
      "Title": "test title 2",
      "Description": "Fake Notice: this is fake",            
      "StartDateTime": "2024-09-18",
      "EndDateTime": "2024-09-26",
      "Planned": true,            
      "ImpactedApps": [
        {
          "Id": "2",
          "Name": "Api 2"
        }
      ],       
      "IsActive": true
    }
  ],
  "CreatedDateTime": "2024-09-18",
  "Version": 1,
  "Title": "Notification Feed"
}

The featchNotices.fulfilled reducer case is passing the entire response payload object and this breaks the invaint.
.addCase(fetchNotices.fulfilled, (state, action) => {             
  state.loading = false;
  state.Notices= action.payload; // <-- not an array! 
})

Solution Suggestions
The code should pass the nested Notices array property to the state value.
.addCase(fetchNotices.fulfilled, (state, action) => {             
  state.loading = false;
  state.Notices = action.payload.Notice; // <-- an array 
})

Alternatively you could return the notices array directly from the Thunk action if you have no need for the other response values.
export const fetchNotices = createAsyncThunk('fetchNotices', async (thunkApi, { rejectWithValue }) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://API_CALL/notice")                          
    const { Notices } = await response.json(); 
    return Notices;
  } catch (error) {
    return rejectWithValue("Something isn't working"); 
  }
}); 

.addCase(fetchNotices.fulfilled, (state, action) => {             
  state.loading = false;
  state.Notices = action.payload; // <-- an array 
})

